# Unable to build dependancy with package in stack

Tags: ros, roslaunch, add-dependencies, sicktoolbox-wrapper, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi and thanks for a great forum!

This is my first question, hope I have the correct tags and so forth.

So, I am trying to build a launch package connecting several packages. Building dependancies and launching nodes directly under the catkin_ws works fine but when I try to depend to "sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper" I receive:

`Cmake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper" with any of the following names:
sicktoolbox_pls_wrapperConfig.cmake
sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper-config.cmake`

The package is found with roscd and rospack find, I can also run the nodes in sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper with rosrun. Could the fact that the package is found in a stack be the problem? I have also tried to build with the dependency directed to the stack without success.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255222/unable-to-build-dependancy-with-package-in-stack/) by [raspet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29434/raspet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-22**:
What do you mean by "inside a stack"? Where did you get this package from? My guess currently is that the package is a rosbuild package, whereas your package is a catkin package. You cannot depend from a catkin to a rosbuild package. You would need to migrate the sick package to catkin as well.

**Comment by [raspet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29434/raspet/) on 2017-02-22**:
Spot on! Did not think about that, I will try to migrate it. Thanks!

The package was found here [link text](https://github.com/hawesie/laser_drivers)
I can prob look at the similar package (without PLS support) here [link text](https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper)?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was indeed that the package was rosbuild, after migrating it to catkin the package is found and can be called within the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [raspet](https://answers.ros.org/users/29434/raspet/) with karma: 16 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0